# How do I properly create multiple documents (books) in memoir? (issues with \book{})

Tags: memoir, parts

Using memoir, I'm trying to set up a collection of individual documents in one LaTeX project (because of lots of cross-references), separated by `book` divisions. E.g.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\book{maindoc}
\tableofcontents* % ISSUE #1: includes all items of seconddoc as well

\chapter{maindoc first chapter}
\chapter{maindoc second chapter}

\book{seconddoc}
\tableofcontents* % ISSUE #1: includes all items of maindoc as well

\setcounter{chapter}{0} % ISSUE #2: ugly reset chapter counter with each book?
\chapter{seconddoc first chapter}
\chapter{seconddoc second chapter}

\end{document}
```

I was expecting a book division to be actually separating individual documents and the ability to create individual ToCs. However, it led me to two unpleasant surprises as indicated in the MWE comments above already:

- ToCs include all items from all books.
- Having to manually reset the counters below the book level.

It feels like my whole approach is wrong. Am I doing something wrong? If this behaviour of books in memoir is by design, how would you create a single LaTeX project consisting of multiple documents?

I've tried the minitoc approach, but it has (known) issues with memoir.

Also, I've had a look at the `titletoc` package, but if I understand the documentation correctly I'll have to manually build all partial ToCs myself again, right?

*Background information: My project will be delivering several individual documents which are readable individually, but they are sharing a single Bibliography, Glossary and are cross-referencing a lot. A requirement is to produce a single PDF.*

Comment: `\book` is just a level similar to `\part`. With a bit of extra work it is possible to selectively switch on and off parts of the toc. BTW: The Ugly reset can be done automatically by dominating the chapter counter with the book counter.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by expanding on this idea: Memoir has hooks to add code into the `.toc` file. We use this to add a callback at strategic points. These callcacks are then altered to control the toc depth at certain points in the TOC it self.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\counterwithin{chapter}{book}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}


\cftinsertcode{PRE-1}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10} }
\cftinsertcode{PRE-2}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10} }
\cftinsertcode{BIB}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{10} }



\newcommand\ShowFirstBook{
  \cftinsertcode{PRE-1}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} }
  \cftinsertcode{PRE-2}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10} }
}

\newcommand\ShowSecondBook{
  \cftinsertcode{PRE-1}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10} }
  \cftinsertcode{PRE-2}{  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} }
}


\begin{document}

\cftinserthook{toc}{PRE-1}
\book{maindoc}
\ShowFirstBook
\tableofcontents* 




\chapter{maindoc first chapter}
\chapter{maindoc second chapter}


\cftinserthook{toc}{PRE-2}
\ShowSecondBook
\book{seconddoc}
\tableofcontents* 

\chapter{seconddoc first chapter}
\chapter{seconddoc second chapter}


\cftinserthook{toc}{BIB}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{s} Test
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```